How can I augment a 1D tablar dataset using an additional 2D dataset?
I have the following two types of datasets:

The dataset-1 is a tabular data that describe 7000 proteins. dataset-1 is only one file.

dataset-2 consists of 7000 individual data files that are 2D martices that also describe 7000 proteins.


dataset-1.dat
ProtNo  ResNo   Label   fet0     fet1     fet2     fet3  fet4  fet5  fet6  fet7    fet8 
0        0      2       0.000    0.000    0.000    1     1     1     1     1        0     
0        1      1       7.057    10.394   0.000    1     1     1     1     1        0     
0        2      1       6.710    9.449    13.140   0     0     0     0     1        0     
0        3      1       6.552    9.752    12.974   0     0     0     0     0        0     
0        4      2       6.544    7.584    11.239   0     0     0     0     0        0     
1        0      2       5.407    5.140    5.159    0     0     0     0     0        0     
1        1      2       5.485    7.378    5.152    0     0     0     0     0        0     
1        2      2       5.723    9.048    9.571    0     0     0     1     1        0     
1        3      2       6.347    9.102    10.812   0     0     0     2     2        0     
1        4      1       6.219    9.620    12.486   0     1     1     3     4        0     
1        5      1       6.412    9.721    12.781   0     0     0     3     4        0     
1        6      1       6.603    10.294   13.140   0     1     1     2     3        0     
1        7      1       7.219    10.586   13.126   0     0     0     2     2        0     
2        0      0       6.939    10.295   13.972   0     0     0     0     1        0     
2        1      0       6.814    10.472   13.764   0     0     0     0     0        0     
2        2      0       7.061    9.189    12.947   0     0     0     0     0        0     
2        3      0       6.872    9.856    11.521   0     0     0     0     0        0     
2        4      2       6.988    9.388    11.337   0     0     0     0     0        0     
2        5      2       6.903    7.889    9.055    0     0     0     0     0        0     
2        6      2       6.378    8.943    9.999    0     0     0     0     0        0     
2        7      1       6.756    10.264   12.361   0     0     0     0     0        0     
2        8      1       6.710    10.006   13.244   0     0     0     0     0        0     
2        9      1       6.539    9.762    13.091   0     0     0     0     0        0     
3        0      0       6.417    9.794    12.952   0     0     0     0     0        0     
3        1      0       6.453    9.944    13.193   0     0     0     0     0        0     
3        2      2       6.842    10.288   13.447   0     0     0     0     0        0     
3        3      2       7.021    8.226    11.805   0     0     0     0     0        0     
... ... ...

dataset-2
distance-matrix-for-protein-0.dat (a 5x5 matrix)

distance-matrix-for-protein-1.dat (an 8x8 matrix)

distance-matrix-for-protein-2.dat (a 10x10 matrix)

distance-matrix-for-protein-3.dat (a 4x4 matrix)

... ... ... 

I have trained an AdaBoost model using dataset-1 and obtained 81% test accuracy.
Now, I want to use dataset-2 to augment dataset-1 so that it increases the model's test accuracy.
How can I do that?
